# Swap ID to String in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar like this

[image]

I want to do a query that shows the `manager_name` instead of the `manager_id`, for example if the `manager_id = 3`, then appears the name of `Perla Rojas`, because she has the `id = 3`

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to provide more information. Anyway, try this:

```
SELECT people.nombre
FROM people
WHERE people.manager_id = 3
```

Note that you should replace  table name with the name of your table